# How to query the root certificate?

Tags: c, windows, cryptoapi

I have a file. This file is digitally signed with our companys certificate. This certificate, has a countersignature (for example by Microsoft ). However this certificate also has a Certification Path, where on the top there is a root certificate ( like Symantec ), under that is another certificate ( like Symantec code signing ), and under that is our companys certificate.

I found [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323809) link, and rewrote it, so i can query everything i need. Well almost everything.
I couldn't figure out, how can i query the information about the root certificate? It's name, or something? Obviousley I am missing something, but i don't know what.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are cryptoAPI functions to establish certificate trust.

I recommend that you go through the following links to understand the basics.

Refer to

[Certificate Chain Verification Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380252%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#certificate_chain_verification_functions)

[Performing X.509 Certificate Verification with CryptoAPI](http://etutorials.org/Programming/secure+programming/Chapter+10.+Public+Key+Infrastructure/10.6+Performing+X.509+Certificate+Verification+with+CryptoAPI/)

Comment: I tried to use `CertGetCertificateChain`, but after i called it, i'm stuck. How do i get the information, from the root certificate?

Comment: What is your end goal? You can open your ROOT store and can identify your root certificate based on some parameter from the certificate such as subject name, serial no etc

Comment: Basicly i want to make sure, that a file is signed with my specific certificate. To do that, i wanted to check the certification path(because AFAIK it can't be faked) and check what the root certificate is(and of course check other things too).